# Is it possible to reduce "git show --name-status --oneline master" to the summary line only?

Tags: git, commit, summary

In the following output, I'd like to exclude lines that start with "A" or "M". Is it possible?

```
 $ git show --name-status --oneline master
    4e8f3e9 Added: f1.txt, f2.txt; modified: master_1.txt
    A       f1.txt
    A       f2.txt
    M       master_1.txt
```

Using "--summary" helps but it still leaves "extra" stuff in it:

```
$ git show --summary --oneline master
4e8f3e9 Added: f1.txt, f2.txt; modified: master_1.txt
 create mode 100644 f1.txt
 create mode 100644 f2.txt
```

What I found interesting here is that although "--oneline" is specified, the output is definitely not limited to one line! :)

While it is possible to process the output, such as piping it thru "grep -v" to obtain the desired result (as suggested below), I'm looking for a solution that is strictly based on git options.

Comment: Have you tried `--summary`?

Comment: Just did, and updated my description to show the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log message itself is one line, you additionally asked for the name-status lines.

"`Added: f1.txt, f2.txt; modified: master_1.txt`" is just (the one line of) text git copied out of the commit message.  If you don't want it showing the name and status of the changed files, do

```
git show -s --oneline master   # `-s` is short for `--no-patch`
```

because the default for showing a commit is to diff up a patch unless you tell it something different.

I see that the git docs are, umm, not organized in the best possible way to make finding that `-s` option easy . . .

Comment: By your pointing out that the one-line text as taken from the commit log made me realize that I was causing my own confusion! :(

The original cmd, git show --name-status --oneline master, turned out to be exactly what I was looking for, i.e., a "listing" of changed files. The commit log was "so concise" that I thought it were a feature of 'git log'., i.e., something git detected and reported. As a result, I thought the lines that started with "A", "M", were redundant! My bad, sorry! :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -v` to remove all lines that start with either 'A' or 'M':

```
git show --name-status --oneline master | grep -v '^[A,M]'
```

Comment: I've updated the description to indicate that I'm interested in a solution that is strictly based on git options.